# Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, load-testing, web-performance

I have a web application which I want to test with Visual Studio Load Test feature.
I could create a load test on my local machine successfully.

My application deployed to a Windows Server and I would like to test it using TFS.
Can I deploy load test with my web application as well?

I need a stress test so I would like to use load test for hours which is quite difficult using my local machine, but unfortunately I don't find any useful tutorial.

My expectation is that I can deploy my load tests, and I can run that without local machine and Visual Studio.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You do not deploy a load test **with** the application. Perhaps you should read about Visual Studio's cloud load test facilities. Please [edit] the question to explain the problem more clearly, also please read the [help] pages about how to write a good question for this site.

Comment: I believe there is not way to "deploy" load test. To run load test you will need Visual Studio.